# delete thousands of inactive users in PHPBB3

Tags: mysql, phpbb3

On my forum I have admin activation activated, but a list of spammers tried to register and now the database is flooded with 17000 inactive users, which slows down everything a bit.

Since there wasn't a real registration since years, I already identified them with this query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM `phpbb_users` 
WHERE `username` NOT LIKE '%]' AND `user_lastpost_time` =0 
AND `user_regdate`>1179679676
```

How can I delete those users? Can I safely delete them? Or do I get 
zombies in other tables then?

Comment: It wasnt invalid, that was just a relict of an export I made

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can prune users from a certain date on

`Administration Control Panel > Users and Groups > Prune Users`

Just select the date and all users newer then that date will be deleted

Comment: I had to search for user `*` and select all users with less than 1 post